# jQuery focusin / focusout. Avoid focusout on submit

Tags: jquery, submit, focusout, focusin

I've got this small script to toggle happy face when focusing in the form:

```
/*  Happy face script */
$('#search').on('focusin', function() {
   $("#smile").removeClass("fa-meh-o");
   $("#smile").addClass("fa-smile-o");
});
$('#search').on('focusout', function() {
   $("#smile").removeClass("fa-smile-o");
   $("#smile").addClass("fa-meh-o");
});
```

However when I `click 'submit'` it goes back to the `focusout` state. How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `focusoutevent` and use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) like,

```
$('#search').on('focusin', function() {
   $("#smile").toggleClass("fa-meh-o fa-smile-o");
});


$('#submit')on('click',function(){
   // your code then you can remove the classes again if not then remove below code
   $("#smile").toggleClass("fa-meh-o fa-smile-o");
});
```

**Updated** you can use `focusin and focusout` with same `toggleClass` like,

```
$('#search').on('focusin focusout', function() {
   $("#smile").toggleClass("fa-meh-o fa-smile-o");
});
```

Comment: Yes, but when I focusout it won't change the class to fa-meh-o. I have to focus again to do that with this code.